# how to separate h4 and p tags

Tags: html, css

ı have a few h4 and p tags. but ı cannot separate some of them even ı set margins for them.

how to overcome it?

```html
<div class="row  text1 offset-md-1">
 <h4>Açıklama</h4>
                                
    <p class="semibold">Materials</p>
```

output:
[h4 and p tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjgH2.png)

```html
<p class="semibold">Installation1</p>

<ul>
    <li>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, incidunt?
       </p>
    </li>
</ul>
                                    
                            
<p class="semibold">Installation2</p>
</div>
```

output:[p tag and following p tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cap3.png)

css:

```css
.text1{
    h4{
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    p{
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        
    }

    ul{
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        list-style-type:disc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use padding instead of margin.

Comment: @Filipe does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using row class in your parent div which is using flexbox and this is messing up your layout.

```
 <div class="">
        <h4>Açıklama</h4>
        <p class="semibold">Materials</p>
        <p class="semibold">Installation1</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex, incidunt?
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p class="semibold">Installation2</p>
    </div>
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Easy option

Use a `<br/>` between the two paras like

```
   <p>.. </p> </br><p></p>
```

or make the div as flexbox

```
     div
     {
      display:flex
      flex-direction:column
     }

    p
   {
    flex:1;
   }
```